# Embedding youtube player in GWT (BST Player API)

Tags: gwt, youtube

I'm developing a GWT application. I need to embed a YouTube video in my application.
I've tried BST player API but I wasn't successful in bringing up the video on the player.
I've downloaded BST `Player.jar` and added it to my buildpath, then inherited the following jars in `gwtapp.gwt.xml`:

```
**inherits name ='com.bramosystems.oss.player.core.Core'**
**inherits name ='com.bramosystems.oss.player.youtube.YouTube'**
```

Then I tried the example given on BST page:

```java
simplePanel = new SimplePanel();
add(simplePanel);
simplePanel.setSize("", "");
try {
    // create the player, specifing URL of media
    player = new ChromelessPlayer("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3CZFfyed3M", "80%", "350px");
    CustomPlayerControl cpc = new CustomPlayerControl(player);
    FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
    fp.add(player);
    fp.add(cpc);
    simplePanel.setWidget(fp); // add player and custom control to panel.
} catch (PluginVersionException e) {
    // required Flash plugin version is not available,
    // alert user possibly providing a link to the plugin download page.
    simplePanel.setWidget(new HTML(".. some nice message telling the " + "user to download plugin first .."));
} catch(PluginNotFoundException e) {
    // required Flash plugin not found, display a friendly notice.
    simplePanel.setWidget(PlayerUtil.getMissingPluginNotice(e.getPlugin()));
}
```

I could see the panel with the YouTube player but I couldn't see the video loading nor playing. I've tried `player.playMedia()` and it was of no help. Any ideas of how to proceed and make the video work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to be passing this URL instead:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/O3CZFfyed3M
```

Comment: this was very help full , but am getting black line all around the video , any way i can remove it..?

Comment: i used this with only simple frame - and it worked fine , refer this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812679/vimeo-embedding-in-gwt

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to embed youtube videos in a GWT vithout using any external library.  Integration level is very simple so you can not make any advanced use.  Here it is the code fragment of a UIBinder template and its corresponding class:

Using and HTMLPanel put an object element like this:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>

       <object ui:field="videoElement"
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
               width="640" height="480" data="">
       </object>

</g:HTMLPanel>

@UIField
ObjectElement videoElement;

[...]

public void displayVideo(String videoId) {
       String videoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/v/".concat(videoId);
       videoElement.setData(videoUrl);  //change data attribute of object element
       String innerHtml = "<param name=\"movie\" value=\""+ videoUrl +"\" />";
       //add param element, of course yo can add as many param elements as needed to customize
       videoElement.setInnerHTML(innerHtml);
}
```

To make it work I needed to put this video view inside a Panel and whenever I wanted to view / update the video clear the panel and add the video view again.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have created this GWT wrapper on top of YouTubes Iframe api library. Which makes it easier to use YouTube api inside gwt check https://github.com/pandurangpatil/gwt-youtube