# Vimeo embedding in gwt

Tags: gwt, vimeo

I tried to embed a video using gwt but I realized that gwt doesn't allow iframe.
[Vimeo suggests](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding) to use this kind of code for embedding. Is there an alternative way to do this?

**Supplement**

After getting the answers I realized that I wanted to add `<frame>` code to an `HTML` element and that does not work but `Frame` works as it is said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GWT Frame class wraps an IFrame and you can find the example use in the javadoc link below.

GWT is in 2.5 version and not 1.5. The link to latest Frame documentation is - http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html

```
public class FrameExample implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
        Frame frame = new Frame("http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+VIDEO_ID);

        // Add it to the root panel.
        RootPanel.get().add(frame);
   }
}
```

If you need to go for third party library then you can BST Player. Make use of Vimeo GWT wrappers from BST Player - http://code.google.com/p/bst-player/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fvimeo-player-provider

I would rather suggest you to stick to GWT Frame api only and not use any third party unless you need some other feature provided by the BST player.

Comment: this is nice - it worked completely fine -  and it also gives complete window of you-tube , some how  BST Player is putting a black line in the frame around the window

Answer (score 0):

GWT supports IFRAME

Check:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/IFrameElement.html

Here you can find the code to embed the video

Download  gwt youtube api and  use like below

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/source/browse/trunk/src/main/resources/com/google/youtube/showcase/Chromeless.gwt.xml?r=105

Then you can find the code to embed in your page .

[Embedding youtube player in GWT (BST Player API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185038/embedding-youtube-player-in-gwt-bst-player-api)

And make sure the path of the video :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have to stick to vimeo this time.